# Super key mapped as Multikey on startup

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, 14.04

After doing the configuration:

```
sem@sem-LIFEBOOK-E754:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
[sudo] password for sem: 
Your console font configuration will be updated the next time your system
boots. If you want to update it now, run 'setupcon' from a virtual console.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
```

After this my super key works again. However, on reboot it goes back to the standard layout.

The steps I took are:

1. Generic 104-key PC
2. English (US)
3. English (US) - English (Dvorak)
4. The default for the keyboard layout
5. No compose key
6. Yes

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 x64

What I tried:

- Every possibility with System Settings > Keyboard Layout
- The /etc/default/keyboard file stays correct all the time, even on reboot.

Fixed it with an ugly hack.

Startup Applications > Add one with

Fill with xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = Super_L"

Wish there was a better solution!

Comment: What do you mean `The /etc/default/keyboard file stays correct all the time`? Editing it with root privileges and saving the file should make the changes persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this https://superuser.com/questions/415772/how-to-map-special-keys-of-the-keyboard-to-some-mappings-in-linux
topic will be useful because it consider more than one tool.

Or that http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/compose.htm